# Ошибка при возвращении в предыдущий viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть `textfield` , 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
которое наследуется с класса `ViewHelper.designForInputText(textField: Region)` , я сделал так, что при клике на него оно ведет в другой `viewcotroller`  - `Regions`

```
@IBAction func RegionClick(_ sender: Any) {
Region.inputView = UIView()
    let newViewController = Regions()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Тут всё работает, и при завершении некоторых операций (в данном случае идет возврат в предыдщий контроллер `Registration` при выборе любой позиции, чтобы не усложнять),

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.tableView{
        let newViewController = Registration()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
    }else{
        let newViewController = Registration()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

уже когда перешло обратно, выдает ошибку
 `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сделать проверку на nil, то точно такая же штука происходит со следующей переменной `Phone`, в чём ошибка с этим возвратом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще то возврат это `uinavigationcontroller.popviewcontroller(animated:)`.
Push - это создание нового контроллера и переход на него. И не понял зачем использовать textField вместо кнопки. Если у вас клик на объект открывает другой контроллер, это работа UIButton.

Comment: Да, спасибо работает. а на счет textfield, то в него будет возвращаться выбранный обьект из джсона потом, эстетически приятнее, когда оно всё одинаково

Comment: дизайн вы можете сделать одинаковый для UIButton и UITextField и UILabel.